How to log directly to Grafana Loki using Serilog with OpenTelemetry
I want to log from Serilog directly to Grafana Loki (no collector) using OpenTelemetry.
Logging without OpenTelemetry to grafana works:
.WriteTo.GrafanaLoki("http://localhost:3100", labels: new List<LokiLabel>()
{
    new LokiLabel()
    {
        Key = "service.name",
        Value = "tests"
    }
})

OpenTelemetry doesn't:
.WriteTo.OpenTelemetry(c =>
{
    c.Endpoint = "http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push";
    c.Protocol = OtlpProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
    c.ResourceAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "service.name", "tests" }
    };
})

I have Loki configured with:
limits_config:
  allow_structured_metadata: true

